# How do I remove the install files for Server 2008 SP1

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2

Windows 7 SP1 allows the user to utilize the "Disk Cleanup" utility to remove unused backup files for uninstalling the service pack.  How do I do this in Server 2008 R2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use the `dism` utility:

`DISM /online /cleanup-Image /spsuperseded`

Comment: On a side note, if you want to install the desktop cleanup tool on W2K8 you need to install the Desktop Experience feature.

Comment: that is definitely the other way to go.